# How to enable Architecture Explorer in VS2010 Beta 2?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I just installed VS2010 Beta 2 from MSDN and could not find the Architecture Explorer. I installed VS2010 primarily to evaluate the new Architeture Explorer features, but could not seem to find this in the menu.

Comment: Which edition did you install? Ultimate? Is there an "Architecture" menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't install the right version.

There are 3 versions:

- Professional
- Premium
- Ultimate

Check [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products/2010/default.mspx) for more details on the differences. For the architecture options:

UML® & Layer diagram viewer - available in Premium and Ultimate

Architecture Explorer - only available in Ultimate

UML 2.0 Compliant Diagrams (Activity, Use Case, Sequence, Class, Component)  - only available in Ultimate

Layer Diagram and Dependency Validation - only available in Ultimate

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I've found there's a bug or a cheat or I don't even know what to call it. If you install the ultimate rc, then install the professional *official release (aka the one you buy), without uninstalling the ultimate rc......you get to keep all the ultimate architecture functionality. Though it will *say it's professional.

You will of course need the professional license.